# Bower's 'overrides' key in bower.json

Tags: bower

I've been scheming through [bower.io](http://bower.io) website to learn how I should define packages for my project in `bower.json`.

However, I've not found any explanation on the `overrides` property.

Take this as an example:

```
"dependencies": {
  "modernizr": "2.8.2",
  "jquery": "1.11.2",
  "bootstrap-sass-official": "~3.3.4"
},
"overrides": {
  "modernizr": {
    "main": "./modernizr.js"
  }
}
```

What does `overrides` do exactly? Would the snippet I pasted install `modernizer 2.8.2`, and then override this with whatever is in the relative path, e.i. `./modernizer.js` ? What's the point of it?